# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: installation, development, composer

I tried to install **magestead** using the command `composer global require "richdynamix/magestead"` and got the following output:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Changed current directory to /home/prabhuchelladurai/.config/composer
Using version ^2.2 for richdynamix/magestead
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- Installation request for richdynamix/magestead ^2.2 -> satisfiable by richdynamix/magestead[2.2].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/console v2.8.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.8
- richdynamix/magestead 2.2 requires symfony/console ^3.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.0, v2.8.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.1, v2.8.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.2, v2.8.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.3, v2.8.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.4, v2.8.8].
- Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v2.8.8) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.8.8].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps your question could be answered quicker by the module author? https://github.com/richdynamix/magestead/issues

Comment: Related: [How to resolve a “Can only install one of:” conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611550/55075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already installed `symfony/console` globally in version 2.8.8 and the version is locked in `~/.config/composer/composer.lock`. This is probably due to some older installation of a different tool. If you are lucky this is also compatible with `symfony/console` 3.1 which magestead needs apparently.

#### Try the following:

```
composer global require --no-update "richdynamix/magestead"
composer global update
```

This command will also update other installed packages. The one that you used ("composer require" with implicit update) does not update other packages that are already installed.

If you still get the error, the version conflict cannot be solved and you can't install all your tools globally. Install magestead in your project instead, or in a separate directory.